# Fiestore In Query Limitation

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use Firebase Functions to send notifications. I'm getting an error because of IN query limitation that i learned today:

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: The query may not have more than 100 filters + sort orders + ancestor total. Currently there are 112 filters

What do you suggest with below code to overcome the problem:

PS: Followers is an array with user ids: [123, 234, 345, ...]

```
exports.clubActivity = functions
  .region('europe-west1')
  .firestore.document('Calendar/{calendarId}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot: any) => {
    // Notification Details
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Yeni Etkinlik',
        body: snapshot.data().owner + ' yeni bir etkinlik oluşturdu.',
        sound: 'default'
      },
      data: {
        type: 'club-activities'
      }
    };
    // Club Info
    const clubInfo = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('Clubs')
      .where('name', '==', snapshot.data().owner)
      .get();
    // Token List
    const allTokens = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('Devices')
      .where('personId', 'in', clubInfo.docs[0].get('followers'))
      .get();
    // Token Array
    const tokens: any[] = [];
    allTokens.forEach(tokenDoc => {
      tokens.push(tokenDoc.id);
    });
    // Notification to Token Array
    if (tokens.length > 0) {
      await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
    } else {
      console.log('Error');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Also on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/l3GELcmdx0E

Comment: What is the type of the `followers` field?

Comment: Array with Ids (number)

Comment: I wrote there also. No any results in Google. This is second. :)

Comment: I will probably use foreach with that array. Then will query devices one by one and push results to another array.

Comment: You mention that you think it is an "IN query limitation", but you should get the following error `FirebaseError: "Invalid Query. 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array."` if you pass an array of size > 10. Not the error you mention. The error is probably coming from another place.

Comment: To me docs are old. New limit is 100 i guess. So there is no search results in Google.Btw same query works with small arrays.

Comment: Mmmhh... not sure the docs are old TBH https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations

Comment: But when i dont use IN or with small arrays there is no problem. What about this? :/

Comment: What is the exact value of this? `clubInfo.docs[0].get('followers')`

Comment: Just user ID's as i said before.

Comment: Well. I would prefer IN but had to use long way. First i used Foreach but it has problems with async. So i used async For to get users devices then tokens.